# How can I animate an element within a fixed position DIV using wow.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css, wow.js

I'm attempting to use **[wow.js](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW)** to animate items as they scroll into view. The items I wish to animate are within a fixed position DIV on the page.

However, wow.js doesn't want to animate the items as they come into view, which I'm guessing is because the browser window itself is not scrolling, only the fixed position DIV which has overflow-y set to scroll.

Any thoughts on getting wow.js to animate the items within the fixed position DIV?

The green backgrounded paragraph is what I'm aiming to have animate.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1do305gs/7/

And the basics:

```js
var wow = new WOW({
    boxClass: 'wow', // animated element css class (default is wow)
    animateClass: 'animated', // animation css class (default is animated)
    offset: 150, // distance to the element when triggering the animation (default is 0)
    live: true, // act on asynchronously loaded content (default is true)
    callback: function (box) {
        // the callback is fired every time an animation is started
        // the argument that is passed in is the DOM node being animated
    }
});
wow.init();
```

```css
#wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/blob/master/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    <p style="background: green; padding: 20px;" class="wow fadeInUp animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are using the right link to `wow.min.js` in your fiddle in the first place. Can you try with [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @TahirAhmed here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/1do305gs/6/ this has a properly attributed one, and the behavior is as described

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: Nope. Haven't found anything to solve this one.